# iTextpdf 5.5.8 With JavaEE method PdfCopy addDocument undefined

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, itextpdf

I am trying to create a pdf with pdfcopy, which is composed with 2 sides of a card.
I am running this with Jetty. but i keep getting this error :

```
[ERROR] The method addDocument(PdfReader) is undefined for the type PdfCopy
```

My code :

```
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfCopy;

public static File exportCards(Person p) throws IOException, DocumentException {   

    Document document = new Document();
    File temp = File.createTempFile("temp_file_name_", ".tmp");

    PdfCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(temp));
    document.open();


    PdfReader reader;
    PdfReader reader_2;
    reader = new PdfReader("FrontStatic.pdf");
    reader_2 = new PdfReader("BackStatic.pdf");
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(temp+"_f"));
    PdfStamper stamper_2 = new PdfStamper(reader_2, new FileOutputStream(temp+"_r"));

    AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
    AcroFields form_2 = stamper_2.getAcroFields();
    form.removeXfa();

    //Recto
    form.setField("form1[0].#subform[0].firstname[0]", p.getFirstName());
    form.setField("form1[0].#subform[0].lastname[0]", p.getLastName());        

    //Verso
    form_2.setField("form1[0].#subform[0].number[0]", String.valueOf(p.getIdentityID()));

    copy.addDocument(reader);
    copy.addDocument(reader_2);

    stamper.close();
    stamper_2.close();
    reader.close();
    reader_2.close();

    //copy.close();
    //document.close();

    return temp;
```

i run the same code on a new program to test only this part, without anything else, and it's running, at least i get the 2 temp file "Stamp" with my data. I do not get the merged document.
Even if i still have a problem with my method to get the final document the error occures only with de Server Web program.

Does someone have an idea ?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your code doesn't obey the rules of logic. Please throw it away and start anew. I don't have the time to give you a better answer, because I have different meetings today. Just now that you ignored the documentation and that you wrote code that can never work.

Comment: I don't understand the code either. You say you want to create one PDF but then create three. You don't mention any forms but then start filling some in. Thus, please adjust your question in a way that your description of what you want and your code do match somewhat.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I am relatively new in programing. But i figured out a way to Merge my pdfs. but here the goal was to print both side of a card ( like ID card for example ). I used two existing pdf to do so ( Front and Back ). I filled those pdf created on Acrobat  LiveCycle to have fields then i just "Stamp" those with my "Person" data.
Maybe i do not understand well how Stamper is working. i created temp files for "auto erased" without being concern about the OS used and just send the result of the PDFcopy.add() to the user by a StreamContent. English isnt my natural language as you can see.